# DynamicResource to change FontSize and TextColor then save in App.Current.Resources

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Use this to change the FontSize and save it in App.Current.Resources , works but not the FontColor

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="defaultFontSize">14</x:Double>
    <Color x:Key="defaultTextColor">#141000</Color>
    <Style x:Key="ALabel" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource defaultTextColor}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource defaultFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Start" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Label
        x:Name="Labeltest3"
        Padding="30,0,30,0"
        Style="{StaticResource ALabel}"
        Text="18" />
```

MainPage.cs
This works for FontSize , Labeltest3.Text is 18 so FontSize = 18

```
private void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(Labeltest3.Text);
        Preferences.Set("FontSize", value);
        App.Current.Resources["defaultFontSize"] = Preferences.Get("FontSize", 14);
    }
```

This is not working for TextColor , what am i missing or doing wrong ?
Tryed all kinds of variations with the Hexcode in a Label.Text but no luck.
Not Changing of the TextColor and no saving of the TextColor

```
private void Button_Clicked_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(Labeltest3.Text);
        Preferences.Set("FontSize", value);
        App.Current.Resources["defaultFontSize"] = Preferences.Get("FontSize", 14);
        Preferences.Set("defaultTextColor", "#ffcc00");
        App.Current.Resources["defaultTextColor"] = Preferences.Get("TextColor", "#141000");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, this works.
Changed this line
Preferences.Set("defaultTextColor", "#ffcc00");

```
private void Button_Clicked_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("FontSize", 8);
       App.Current.Resources["defaultFontSize"] = Preferences.Get("FontSize", 14);

        Preferences.Set("TextColor", "#ffcc00");
        App.Current.Resources["defaultTextColor"] = Preferences.Get("TextColor", "#141000");
    }
```